# Static validateset parameter not showing after Dynamic parameter input

Tags: powershell

I found the following situation using a mix of dynamic and static parameters and I am wondering if I am doing things wrong or if there's a bug / unexpected behavior with the auto-completion facing this situation.

I have two functions.

```
Test-MyExampleSet -Service 'Service 1' # Auto-Completion does not suggest -Name parameter

Test-MyExample -Service 'Service 1' -Name AdminTools # Auto-completion works fine.
```

The first one have a static parameter using a validateset and a dynamic parameter.

The second one have a static parameter (string) and a dynamyc parameter. 
When using the Test-MyExampleSet, after adding the -Service parameter, the auto-completion does not shows the -Name dynamic parameter anywhere.

Repeating the exact same thing with the Test-MyExample, which is the same exact thing minus the validate set, works properly.

Is is related to the way I declared the dynamic parameter or is there really issues with mixing dynamic parameters and static parameters ?

**Sample Code with the 2 function definitions**

```
$include = @("Service 1", "Service 2")

function Test-MyExample
{
[cmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Position=-0,Mandatory=$false)]
     [String]$Service
  )
   DynamicParam
    {
        # Set the dynamic parameters name
        $ParameterName = 'Name'

        # Create the dictionary
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

        # Create the collection of attributes
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

        # Create and set the parameters' attributes
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.ValueFromPipeline = $true
        $ParameterAttribute.ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
        $ParameterAttribute.Position = 0
        $ParameterAttribute.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
        # Add the attributes to the attributes collection
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

        # Generate and set the ValidateSet
        $arrSet = [Enum]::GetNames('System.Environment+SpecialFolder')
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)

        # Add the ValidateSet to the attributes collection
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

        # Create and return the dynamic parameter
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
        return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }

    Begin
    {
        # Bind the parameter to a friendly variable
        $Name = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
    }

    Process
    {
        $Name | ForEach-Object { [Environment]::GetFolderPath($_) }
    }
    }

    function Test-MyExampleSet
{
[cmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
  [ValidateSet('Service 1','Service 2')]
  [Parameter(Position=-0,Mandatory=$false)]
     [String]$Service
  )
   DynamicParam
    {
        # Set the dynamic parameters name
        $ParameterName = 'Name'

        # Create the dictionary
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

        # Create the collection of attributes
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

        # Create and set the parameters' attributes
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.ValueFromPipeline = $true
        $ParameterAttribute.ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
        $ParameterAttribute.Position = 0
        $ParameterAttribute.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
        # Add the attributes to the attributes collection
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

        # Generate and set the ValidateSet
        $arrSet = [Enum]::GetNames('System.Environment+SpecialFolder')
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)

        # Add the ValidateSet to the attributes collection
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

        # Create and return the dynamic parameter
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
        return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }

    Begin
    {
        # Bind the parameter to a friendly variable
        $Name = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
    }

    Process
    {
        $Name | ForEach-Object { [Environment]::GetFolderPath($_) }
    }
    }




Test-MyExampleSet -Service 'Service 1' # Auto-Completion does not suggest -Name parameter

Test-MyExample -Service 'Service 1' -Name AdminTools # Auto-completion works fine.
```